# ExtJS4 How to set TreePanels root node from JSON

Tags: json, tree, extjs4, root

I want to create TreePanel using ExtJS4. So I'm sending JSON to proxy reader which has following format

```
{
    "text": "en",
    "children": {
        "text": "/",
        "children": [{
                "text": "/page",
                "children": [{
                        "text": "/page/new",
                        "children": [],
                        "leaf": true,
                        "expanded": false
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "/page/remove",
                        "children": [],
                        "leaf": true,
                        "expanded": false
                    }
                ],
                "leaf": false,
                "expanded": false
            },
            {
                "text": "/home",
                "children": [],
                "leaf": true,
                "expanded": false
            }
        ],
        "leaf": false,
        "expanded": true
    }
}
```

How do I have to configure my Store if I want `en` node to be my root node.

```
Ext.define('Example.store.WebItems', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    model: 'Example.model.Item',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'some/url',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'children' // Is this correct?
        }
    },
    root: // What should I write here?
});
```

When I define `TreeStore`'s root as `root: 'My Root'` it will add new root, but I want to use root defined in `JSON`.

So my questions are:

1. How to use root node from JSON instead of defining it manualy?
2. Do I have to define root node in proxy reader and TreeStore as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Response has to have `root`.

For example:

```
{
     MyRoot: {
         "text": "en",
         "children": {
             "text": "/",
             "children": [{
                 "text": "/page",
                 "children": [{
                     "text": "/page/new",
                     "children": [],
                     "leaf": true,
                     "expanded": false
                 }, {
                     "text": "/page/remove",
                     "children": [],
                     "leaf": true,
                     "expanded": false
                 }],
                 "leaf": false,
                 "expanded": false
             }, {
                 "text": "/home",
                 "children": [],
                 "leaf": true,
                 "expanded": false
             }],
             "leaf": false,
             "expanded": true
         }
     }
 }
```

In this example `root` is `MyRoot`. Now you have to "tell" reader that your `root` is `MyRoot`:

```
        // ...
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'MyRoot'
        }
    },
    //root: this config is not needed now
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just want to add that `Ext.tree.Panel`'s property `rootVisible` has to be set to `false`. Otherwise no tree will be loaded.

Comment: Setting rootVisible to false was the secret I was looking for...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per I know, you need to specify root as following:

```
root: {
    text: 'en',
    id: 'src',
    expanded: true '
}
```

Try the above code snippet it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Unfortunately it just adds root manually, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

May be late but for others , wrap the `JSON` inside array `[]` just like this :

```
[{
    "text": "en",
    "children": {
        "text": "/",
        "children": [{
            "text": "/page",
            "children": [{
                "text": "/page/new",
                "children": [],
                "leaf": true,
                "expanded": false
            }, {
                "text": "/page/remove",
                "children": [],
                "leaf": true,
                "expanded": false
            }],
            "leaf": false,
            "expanded": false
        }, {
            "text": "/home",
            "children": [],
            "leaf": true,
            "expanded": false
        }],
        "leaf": false,
        "expanded": true
    }
}]
```

Remove the reader block

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'MyRoot'
}
```

Add root block :

```
root: {
    text: 'en',
    id: 'src',
    expanded: true '
}
```

Add `rootVisible: false` in `treepanel`.