# Extjs: Can I set the root node of a tree store by proxy?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want my json to be like:

```
{
   root: [{
        text: 'myroot',
        expanded: true
        children: [{
         ....
        }]
    }]
}
```

so the tree will be like:

```
MyRoot
|-Children1
|-Children2
```

without setting root in the tree store, which means I can set the root node's name from server,
is that possible?

Comment: Try that from other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6957791/2995099
It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using [metachange event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-event-metachange) of Ext.data.TreeStore.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {

    // Your store settings

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'yourData.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
    }

    listeners: {
        metachange: function (store, meta) {
            store.setRootNode(meta.root);
        }
    }
});
```

In this case, your JSON should be as follows:

```
{
    metaData: {
        root: {
            text: 'My Root',
            expanded: true,
            "data": []
        }
    },
    data: [
        // Your data
    ]
}
```

In fact, using this event you can send any settings for store, treepanel etc. from the server.